# Link in SMS from android app

Tags: android, android-sms

I want to send a link in SMS from my android application. I am able to do so. But whole body doesn't reflect as a link. Part of SMS is not shown as a link. Any help how to do so in android app.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
selectedSMSMessage = "http://www.mydeeplink.com?SignInId=" + SignIn.userid;

smsManager.sendTextMessage(selectedContact, null, selectedSMSMessage, null, null);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message Sent",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @yatin deokar Any Idea how to do so.

Comment: I guess you can use a regular expression to verify the message before send it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String id = SignIn.userid;

    String trimmedID = id.trim();

    String selectedSMSMessage = "http://www.mydeeplink.com?SignInId=" + trimmedID;

}
```

Comment: SMS link broke rom "?" and "=" sign

Comment: @MohammadAamir sorry but couldn't understand you.

Comment: I am able to send SMS successfully. I am sending a deeplink in sms. But it brokes at a special character like "?" or "=".

Comment: link broke in sms at "?"